# Relative constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Look at the image please:

[image: r3gv4kzjb]

I want to set up constraints for inside lines, but I don't know how to do that. I have 7 images of lines (on image you can see 3) and some of them always don't show on smaller displays for ex. on iPhone 4s.

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve exactly. What is the desired outcome, what is your current setup and where does it fail?

Comment: So, I want this: http://postimg.org/image/9crsqzylj/

And I've got this: http://postimg.org/image/ekg0cx8qh/

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to add the links directly into my question

Comment: I doubt designing that view in IB is a very good idea: looks like a job for a collection view.